# How can I tell if the libcurl installed has asynchronous DNS enabled?

Tags: proxy, dns, tornado, libcurl

I would like to try and use Tornado's proxying capabilities. For this, the documentation tells me, I need to have libcurl compiled with asynchronous DNS resolver.

I have a version of libcurl installed via yum (7.29), but I can't figure out how to tell whether it was built with asynchronous DNS resolution or not.

If it doesn't, is there a way to enable it, or do I have to build it from scratch? It seems like the latter is the only option I could find so far, hoping I missed something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [curl_version_info](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_version_info.html)() and check the returned struct and its 'features' field:

```
   int features;             /* bitmask, see below */
```

If that field has the bit CURL_VERSION_ASYNCHDNS set, you know this libcurl build resolves names asynchronously. Using either threads or it was built to use c-ares.

If that bit is not set, it was built to use synchronous name resolves.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, if you have command-line version of curl installed, you may run `curl --version`. To install curl on alpine run `apk add curl`

Example output:

```
root@ae5870274e10:/mnt/src# curl --version
curl 7.38.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.38.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1t zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.29 libssh2/1.4.3 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

and look for `AsynchDNS` keyword

Comment: How can I tell if libcurl is built with c-ares or the threaded resolver ?

Comment: @NicoAdrian just compiled newest curl + c-ares and this is what I get when typing `curl --version`

```
./curl --version
curl 7.78.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.78.0 zlib/1.2.8 c-ares/1.17.2 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.4.31
Release-Date: 2021-07-21
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap ldap mqtt pop3 rtmp rtsp smtp telnet tftp 
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile libz UnixSockets
```

As you can see, `c-ares/1.17.2` string is present right at the beginning.

Comment: I don't have the `c-ares` string but I do have `AsynchDNS` in it. So I guess my curl is built with threaded resolver

Comment: Yes, `c-ares` seems to be a binary option at the moment.